# Which is the Best data structure for implementing a dictionary and which algorithm suitable for search?

Tags: java, netbeans

Best data structure for implementing a dictionary and which algorithm suitable for search?
I just want to search the word and return meaning from database.

Requirements are that, start typing the first few letters of a word it would need to popup the remaining characters as in auto-complete.

Answer (score 1):

For search a `Hashmap` is the way to go because it was built for searching.
Specifically in your case you would want the word to be the key and the meaning to be value. If it has multiple definitions you can use a `List<String>` to hold many definitions.

Comment: HashMap would not be suitable if he wants to search by pieces of the word. Like if the requirements are that you start typing the first few letters of a word it would need to popup the remaining characters as in auto-complete. But since @NASWEEF never specified we can't know that.

Comment: @Kon good point.. but then this keeps me thinking for your case which data structure would you recommend or think would be good ?

Comment: @user641887 traditionally these types of things are implemented with a Trie. It's a somewhat common interview questions/programming challenge.

Comment: This question is for my Bachelor Degree project, but I completed the project with - created multiple table for each English letters. A_Dictionary, B_Dictionary, C_Dictionary.........Z_Dictionary.                                                                                 SELECT Malayalam_Meaning FROM FirstLetter_Dictionary WHERE word LIKE 'EnteredLetters%'.  while entering each letter tried to read data from db, and saved in ArrayList. I dont know is it better or not. thank @Kon for your valuable reponse.